# Create custom code to work around missing rename action on Azure Logic App FTP Connector

Tags: c#, azure, ftp, azure-logic-apps

We are converting a existing C# console app to a Azure solution.
Pretty basic need:

1. Store files as blobs that need to be FTP'd to a client.
2. Insert messages into a Service Bus Topic with a JSON format for file name etc.
3. Have a logic app subscribe to the topic and FTP the file.

The ftp server is our customers and I cannot change its setup.

It starts processing files as soon as they are put on there and meet a certain naming style.

In the past all I do is put temp_ at the front of the file, then create it, then rename it.

Perfect.

We already have this working using standard .Net code, but now I am trying to get it to work using a Azure Logic app as detailed above.

Using a 'Create File' under the FTP connector.  If I create it using the proper name it fails as the FTP server grabs the file before Azure is done creating it.

There is no rename functionality in the FTP connector -- can somebody *please* tell me I am missing something??

Joe

UPDATE 5-24-18
From Microsoft Tech Support:

> After looking further into this, this is not going to be doable using
>   the out-of-the-box FTP connector.
>
> The logic apps workaround would be to do this from custom code. You
>   could use the FTP connector’s Create File task to create the file on
>   the FTP server using the temporary name. Then, you could call a custom
>   Azure Function that would log into the FTP server and rename the file.
>   This would require you to create a custom function.
>
> See the following link for more details on calling Azure Functions
>   from logic apps:
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions

I am going to attempt to do this and if I can get it to work post it as an answer.

If anybody wants to take a swing at helping me that would be great!

*The bigger question I guess here is "**why**"?*

Why go through all this?  Why not just use a C# function right from the beginning?  The answer is partially just to have the experience of using Service Bus / Topics etc...plus if they ever DO update their FTP connector it will be a easy fix then.  But I am still open to other answers or options.

BTW - please vote for that change here if you think it would be helpful:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/19499953-add-rename-action-to-sftp-ftp-storage-etc-connect

Comment: I guess the logic app team is pushing to use their product but if it does not match your requirements just go for functions

Comment: Pretty much. I have it about 80% complete and will post all the code and basic instructions on what needs to be setup in Azure here in case somebody else needs to do the same thing.